# flaky proxy on virtual machine

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, proxy, ubuntu-12.04

I have been battling this for several hours and coming stuck.

I use windows XP and a VM box with ubuntu.  I have to use the proxy to connect to the internet at work.  However I use ubunutu to check development code.

Some info
Xp machine has a proxy setup and no internet browsing problems with XP machine
VM Network setup as bridged connection and the proxy set to the same IP that the XP machine uses.

[image]

First problem firefox keeps prompting me for proxy auth?  However if I ignore it it does let me get through however its temper*mental* and stops altogether?

[image]

Also the wget command is working for www.google.com

[image]

but it isnt for bbc.co.uk or https://packagist.org/packages.json.

[image]

So I have a flakey internet connection on the VM and it must be something to do with how I have set it up.  Not sure what my options are?  Install a proxy server on my XP host machine that sends requests to the main proxy?..

Comment: DO any of the solutions in http://askubuntu.com/questions/42507/how-can-i-configure-internet-proxy-on-vm work for you?

Comment: nope tried changing back and forth from nat to bridged but with bridged I get some connectivity.  not sure what Cntlm Authentication Proxy is do I install that on the ubunut machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve it by entering in my windows logon onto the firefox popup.  It seemed to have made the proxy accept future requests even if not from firefox such as wget